# When to use a mutex and when not

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic

I have a global variable named `my_list` containing a linked list (i.e., the variable is a pointer to the first member of the list). This variable can be edited only by two threads, thread A and thread B. In case the list becomes empty, the variable is set to `NULL`. When this happens the variable is set to `NULL` first, and afterwards the memory is freed.

As it is edited by two threads, I use a mutex every time thread A or thread B touch the `my_list` variable. Nothing unusual so far.

But then comes a third thread, thread C. This thread will never ever touch the linked list in any way, but it will need to know from time to time whether the list is empty or not. So, the only thing thread C will do is

```
if (my_list) {

    do_something_completely_unrelated();

}
```

Do I have to use a mutex for that? I believe it is an atomic operation, so no mutex is required. Is this correct?

**EDIT**

I will add here a bit of context. The reason why I would like to avoid using a mutex is that the list gets updated rarely (always), but the check coming from thread C happens every few milliseconds, so the less operations the better.

If the list appears to be non-`NULL`, *then a proper check using a mutex is triggered by thread C*, and if it is confirmed that the list is not empty thread C stops its obsessive check.

Comment: ***This thread will never ever touch the linked list in any way, but it will need to know from time to time whether the list is empty or not.*** Then thread C is also "touching" this linked list isn't it? It's trying to read (check if list is NULL).

Comment: *"I believe it is an atomic operation"* - I suspect you harbor doubt, otherwise you wouldn't be asking. Short version: unless specifically configured to use atomic artifacts of your implementation (if they exist), any data that can be written and read concurrently needs concurrency protection. Anything else is a race condition just waiting to happen. That includes checking `my_list` for NULL or otherwise. If some writer somewhere can change that to NULL, you *must* protect it somehow (via platform atomics, or a mutex). "touching" doesn't just mean "writing" .

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you. But concretely _what could happen bad_? Let's say the variable is `NULL` but is being changed right now by thread A to address `xxxxxx`. Thread C attempts to read it. What value can it get? Either `NULL` or `xxxxxx`, and both are fine. Am I wrong in assuming that the program will not crash?

Comment: @madmurphy If it doesn't matter if you get the correct value, why bother checking?

Comment: @kiner_shah Technically thread C never reads the content of the list, it only reads the numerical value of a global pointer and checks if it is zero.

Comment: @klutt Because the list gets edited rarely, but thread C checks often. If it misses the correct value now it will get it right next time. There is no way the list can change in between (the complete explanation is longer than this, but trust me).

Comment: Is there any problem of using a mutex? Have you noticed a performance drop?

Comment: @klutt I am not worried about performance, I am worried about blocking operations (it is a graphical user interface). I have not implemented this part just yet, I am in the planning phase.

Comment: What is the problem with blocking? Just wait until the mutex is unlocked?

Comment: If `do_something_completely_unrelated();` doesn't do anything with the list contents, but only needs to be called if the list was not empty in the immediate past, you could acquire the mutex to check the list, and release it before calling the function.

Comment: @klutt Waiting in a graphical user interface is never the optimal solution. Explaining the whole context is really complex, which is why I was asking about it from a theoretical point of view. I am basically trying to create a multi-thread interface for a single-thread event-driven application (not written by me). As I said... it's complicated.

Comment: @IanAbbott “Acquiring the mutex” might potentially lead to a waiting scenario if the mutex is already taken.

Comment: @madmurphy See last section of my answer for a proposed solution

Comment: Re, "what could happen bad?" In many implementations, nothing. But, a different question: What is _allowed_ to happen bad? The answer to that is, absolutely anything could happen. When you break the rules of C++ (e.g., by allowing threads to share data without proper "synchronization,") then the behavior of your program is _undefined._ What _could_ happen bad? You could try an experiment, and it works. Then you build it into a product and you test the \*\*\*\* out of it, and you sell it, and it works. Then Microsoft puts out a Windows update, and it _stops_ working for all of your customers.

Answer (score 5):

### TL;DR

According to the standard, it is undefined behavior to read a variable when it's written if at least one of the operations is non-atomic.

### Longer answer

From comment section, you seem to wonder if it will crash your program, or if the worst thing that may happen is that you get the wrong value. Your comment, emphasis mine:

> Thank you. But concretely what could happen bad? Let's say the variable is `NULL` but is being changed right now by thread A to address `xxxxxx`. Thread C attempts to read it. What value can it get? Either `NULL` or `xxxxxx`, and both are fine. **Am I wrong in assuming that the program will not crash?**

I would say that this simple check will *most likely* not cause your program to crash. The check operation is safe in the sense that you will *most likely* get a value. The value may be wrong, but the check alone will *most likely* not crash your program.

However, it IS undefined behavior:

> The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

[C18 Standard, section 5.1.2.4, paragraph 35](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c2x/n2434.pdf#subsubsection.5.1.2.4)

Then you posted this follow up comment:

> This is actually not so important, but am I correct in assuming that if thread A is changing the value from `NULL` to `xxxxxx` (or vice versa) I will definitely not get `yyyyyy`, but either NULL or `xxxxxx`?

Here I'd say your assumption is wrong. AFIK, there's nothing in the standard that says that a pointer assignment needs to be an atomic operation, and I would be surprised if it was. And as I mentioned above, it IS undefined behavior.

### Suggested solutions

##### Use `_Atomic` keyword

Declare the list with the `_Atomic` qualifier. It has some limitations. For instance:

1. It's not a mandatory feature, so it might reduce portability
2. It cannot be used with arrays
3. If used with a struct, the fields of the struct cannot be accessed individually

2 and 3 should not matter to you, since the list is just a pointer.

Read about `_Atomic` here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic

##### Use a copy that doesn't get updated on each access

If `_Atomic` is not an option, here is a solution in pseudo code:

```
if ( now() - lastUpdated > ms ) // If it was more than ms milliseconds since last update  
    lock(myMutex)
    myListCopy = myList
    unlock(myMutex)
    lastUpdated = now()

if(myListCopy) 
    do_something_completely_unrelated();
```

`lastUpdated` and `myListCopy` are preferably variables that are local to the function, but the important part is that thread A and B never touches them.

Comment: Thank you, klutt. This is actually not so important, but am I correct in assuming that if thread A is changing the value from `NULL` to `xxxxxx` (or vice versa) I will definitely not get `yyyyyy`, but either `NULL` or `xxxxxx`?

Comment: You cannot assume that reading a non-null value from `my_list` indicates the list is not empty. Reading without synchronization is undefined behavior

Comment: @LWimsey But how can I obtain an atomic operation then? I only need a simple empty/non-empty answer, is there a way to avoid using a mutex for that?

Comment: @LWimsey Do you have a source for the claim that it's UB? I'm trying to find one but I have failed so far.

Comment: @madmurphy without using the mutex, the `my_list` pointer must be an atomic type

Comment: @klutt Unsynchronized R/W access to a variable is called a 'data race' and it is defined by the C standard

Comment: @LWimsey Found it. Updated answer.

Comment: @LWimsey Thank you again. I have one last final question. Is `_Atomic [datatype] * [variable name]` guaranteed to be supported by every compiler that comforms to the standard? Or is it one of these optional things where the standard says “A pointer declared as `_Atomic` might or might not be supported by compilers”?

Comment: @madmurphy The memory model was introduced in the 2011 standard (C11). If a compiler is C11 compliant, atomics are supported.

Comment: @madmurphy @LWimsey That is not quite true. If a C11 compliant implementation defines the macro `__STDC_NO_ATOMICS__` as the integer constant `1` then it need not support atomic types, the `_Atomic` type qualifier, or the `<stdatomic.h>` header.

Comment: @klutt The 2 seconds in your suggested solution is a really long time for what I have to do. The discovery of the changed list must happen almost immediately in thread C. I think I will opt for `_Atomic`. After all, if not for a case like this, what was the `_Atomic` qualifier created for?

Comment: @IanAbbott Thank you for the info about `__STDC_NO_ATOMICS__`.

Comment: @madmurphy Sure, but you're free to change to whatever value you like. And yes, `_Atomic` is an option.